# grails replace method with an optional parameter by a closure

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.2

I have two class:

```
class Foo {
    String doSomething(String a = 'Not working') {
        return a
    }
}
```

And I want to replace 'doSomething' in a test but it dosent work

```
@Test
void testMethodIWannaTest() {
    Foo.metaClass.doSomething = {String a -> return 'Working'}

    assert new Foo().doSomething() == 'Working' //THIS TEST FAIL, return 'Not Working'
}
```

If I remove the optional param, it works.

Did someone know how to fix this ?

*I know the test doesn't really make sens, it's just to show my point

What do I do wrong ? Is it possible to do it without using 'mockFor' ?

Comment: If you're using Groovy < 2.0 I'd recommend using GMock for this sort of mocking rather than metaprogramming. Currently GMock doesn't work with Groovy >= 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a default parameter generates two methods:

```
String doSomething()         { doSomething( 'Not working' ) }
String doSomething(String a) { a }
```

So try setting the no-arg function (as that's the one you're going to call:

```
Foo.metaClass.doSomething = { -> doSomething( 'Working' ) }
```

Comment: If done this test and all passes

`Foo.metaClass.doSomething = {-> return 'Working1'}`
`Foo.metaClass.doSomething = {String a -> return 'Working2'}`

`assert new Foo().doSomething() == 'Working1'`
`assert new Foo().doSomething('toto') == 'Working2'`